# Не получается реализовать функцию вывода изображения по клику на Pyqt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Не получается реализовать функцию вывода изображения по клику на кнопку, выдает ошибку:

> picture_1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
      def __init__(self,parent=None):
          QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
          uic.loadUi("MyForm2.ui",self)
          self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.picture_1(self))

      def picture_1(self):
          pixmap = QPixmap('Image1.jpeg')
          self.label7.setPixmap(pixmap)
if __name__=="__main__":
      import sys
      app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      window=MyWindow()
      window.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: попробуйте заменить строку `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.picture_1(self))` на `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.picture_1)`

Comment: спасибо огромное, выручили очень

Comment: @S.Nick, оформите комментарий в виде ответа :)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте заменить строку self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.picture_1(self)) на self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.picture_1) – S. Nick вчера